# "Not clear", "not precise", "not accurate", "not exact" — Which of them is it possible to use when a photo or contours are vague?

Tags: word-usage, difference, usage

I'd like to understand the difference between "clear", "precise", "accurate" and "exact", when we're talking about a vague image.

---

A blurred photo of a town:
[image: a blurred photo of a town]

**(1)** *The photo is not **clear***.
**(2)** *The photo is not **precise***.
**(3)** *The photo is not **accurate***.
**(4)** *The photo is not **exact***.

Which of these sentences are appropriate for the picture above and which are not?

---

A line with the blurred contour:
[image: a line with the blurred contour]

**(5)** *The line is not **clear***.
**(6)** *The line is not **precise***.
**(7)** *The line is not **accurate***.
**(8)** *The line is not **exact***.

Which of these sentences are appropriate for the picture above and which are not?

---

Update:

Based on James' answer, I tried to make the implied meaning of (5-8) more clear:
**(5a)** *The contour of the line is not **clear***.
**(6a)** *The contour of the line is not **precise***.
**(7a)** *The contour of the line is not **accurate***.
**(8a)** *The contour of the line is not **exact***.

So, which of (5a-8a) are appropriate for the picture above and which are not?

Comment: I don't see the point of this question. In both examples, the "most natural" phrasing is just ***a blurred photo*** and ***a blurred line***. Choosing between (less precise) alternatives is a waste of time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You can "see the point of this question" in its first sentence: "_I'd like to understand the difference between "clear", "precise", "accurate" and "exact", when we're talking about a vague image._"

Comment: In none of the images would I use any of the adjectives listed, instead my preference would be *blurred* "out of focus"  or "fuzzy". I'm sure dictionaries give examples of usage and common collocation for each word.

Answer (score 1):

These are all bad ways to describe the picture, the line or the contour.  The only one that might work is "The photo is not clear"  All the others are wrong.

You need to know what the intent is.  You can assume the photograph is intended to show a picture of a town.  It doesn't show it clearly, so it is "not clear".

The intent of the line is unknown.  It might be exactly as intended.  In which case you wouldn't say it wasn't clear, precise, accurate, or exact.  None of those are a good description.

It is better to say "It is blurred"  That works for the photo too.

Comment: You said (1) is possible. But I still continue not to know if (2), (3) and (4) are possible or not.

Comment: @Loviii - what part of 'no' don't you understand?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Where do you see the "no" relating to (2-4)?

Comment: @Loviii - it is implied.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Could you also comment (5a-8a)? Thanks.

Comment: All sentences without the word *clear* are wrong. All the synonyms you offer work in other settings, not here. Maybe an explanation can be clear, precise, accurate or exact.

Comment: __Accurate_ and _exact_ are used of things like measurements and calculations, not pictures.